# How do I set all bone rotations to zero when exporting to FBX or GLB?

Tags: rigging, .fbx, gltf

I am working on a project in ThreeJs where I want to use a third party avatar model that is rigged. In the avatar model, all the rigs are rotated to $0$ when it is in T-pose.

I want my custom 3D models to have the same rig as well, so I attached the same bones and exported all assets from Blender.

But unfortunately, I could see that after exporting from Blender, all bone rotation values in all hierarchy levels change to $-90$. Also when I export the third party avatar from Blender, the rotation values are set to random values ($-90$).

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!